# Should the "identify this game" tag be removed?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

It seems a little like the existence of the "identify this game" tag invites submission of "identify this game" questions.  Seeing as how this branch of questions is no longer desired on this site, should the tag itself be removed?

Comment: It's deleted now. Be aware that new users will not be able to re-create them, so they may tag them differently (no, they won't refrain from asking them :) )

Comment: @JuanManuel with a tag like this, I'm honestly not sure that will help in reducing their numbers, but it will make them harder to find...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags are tricky to remove entirely. They're like weeds. Once they've been created, nothing can kill them -- except the system's automatic culling of tags not used on questions.

[identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) has not been not around long enough to trigger this inactivation removal, and mods cannot expedite this process. The only hope for an earlier removal would be mucking around in the database directly, but that's not exactly viable, nor is it something that should be necessary in this case.

In short - just make sure to close / vote to delete any new ITG questions that pop up, and the tag will disappear from Gaming's database on its own.

Comment: in addition, blacklisting the tag just ensures that other, less applicable tags will be used instead

Comment: @BenBrocka Mods can't do that either, can they?

Comment: @JohntheGreen Nope, it'd have to be by the SE team I do believe, and I don't think this is a problem worthy of that. Meta tags were blacklisted because they were applied to tons of worthy questions, in this case the tag is always applied to Qs to be deleted anyway